# How to Create Analysis service Data Source for SharePoint Dashboard designer?

Tags: sql-server, database, business-intelligence, sql-analysis-services

We don't have data warehouse, we want to add Reports in SharePoint dashboard designer from SharePoint list as data-source, but Reports accepts only analysis service as Data source.

So can anyone guide me step by step guide how to create Analysis Service Data-Source ( cubes, Di-mentions, measures) from SharePoint lists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out things are not as simple as i thought, please check [my blog post](http://sharepoint497.blogspot.com/2012/11/business-intelligence-report-in.html) to find out details.